How is the reference line in QuantilePlot defined?
We know that, when using QuantilePlot to visualize data, a reference line will be added by default. For example the red line below:
data = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 100];

plot = QuantilePlot[data, ReferenceLineStyle -> Red]


Extracting the line is easy enough, of course:
Cases[plot, _Line, Infinity]

(* {Line[{{0.109909, 0.}, {0.869301, 0.977172}}]} *)

But how is this line defined? (We already have this interesting answer discussing how the points are generated, but the reference line isn't discussed there. )

If you look in the documentation for QuantilePlot, under option Method, you will see different possible methods, such as "Quartile", "Fit", "Diagonal", "Reference" ... Default option is "Quartile", which simply uses the 1st and the 3rd quartile of data to draw the reference line. For other methods, look into System`QuantilePlotDump`referenceLine.
data = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 100];
plot = QuantilePlot[data, ReferenceLineStyle -> Red];
plotdata = First@Cases[plot, Point[d__] :> d, Infinity];

{xQ1, xQ3} = Quartiles[plotdata[[All, 1]]][[{1, 3}]];
{yQ1, yQ3} = Quartiles[plotdata[[All, 2]]][[{1, 3}]];

Show[plot, Graphics[{Green, Thickness[0.01], Line[{{xQ1, yQ1}, {xQ3, yQ3}}]}]]


